# Cannot add the ODBC Oracle Driver

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I am trying to add the ODBC driver for Oracle so that i can make an excel query. I have Win7 64bit and Office2010 64bit.

I have already tried to install:

Oracle - Oraclient12Home1
Oracle - OraDB11ghome1
codeproject.com/Questions/239773/how-to-configure-microsoft-odbc-for-oracle-in-win
stackoverflow.com/questions/11873160/connect-to-an-oracle-db-using-odbc

It just won't add.

Both:
The 32-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64 folder.
The 64-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32 folder.

Have the below drivers only.
![ODBC Data Source Administrator][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERYMM.png

Comment: Make sure you're able to connect to Oracle. For that run from command line sqlplus user/password@hostname.network/remote_service_name and then a simple query like "select 1 from dual;" should return results but not errors.

Comment: Hello. How will this help me add the ODCB oracle driver in the attached?

Comment: Found the solution. I had to install this particular package:
ODBC_64bit_instantclient_11_2